# RVM finding system gems' executables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, rvm, apt-get

I have installed RVM along with ruby versions. However if I fire up the console and run the command rails server, bundle install, etc. I get this error

```
bash: /usr/bin/rails: /usr/bin/ruby1.8: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

But if I run `rvm use 1.9.2` first, then everything is ok. I tried using `rvm use --default 1.9.2' but nothing changed. Does this mean it uses a different ruby from the ones in RVM? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Add the output of `rvm info` to your question by editing it.

Comment: `rvm` doesn't automatically install `rails`. After you install a specific Ruby interpreter, you need to install whatever gems you want (including `rails`) for that interpreter. The problem seems to be that you installed 1.9.2 and set it as a default, but never installed `rails` for that interpreter.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**Explanation of rubygems bin folders and PATH**

Oh. You didn't have rails installed in your rvm ruby, but you did in your system ruby.

Individual gems, like `rails` can have a `bin` directory that will contain executable helper scripts. Your system default rubygems is making symlinks from your system /usr/bin/ dir into the gem's `bin` folder for these helper executables.

RVM provides a similar facility, except instead of polluting the system /usr/bin dir, it just appends *its* `~/.rvm/gems/#{rvm_gemset_string}/bin` folder to the PATH environment variable.

---

**Importing system Rubygems list into your new rvm rubies' gem directories**

RVM by default will not import your gems from your system ruby installation into your rvm ruby installs. It makes a full clean fork of the entire ruby system including rubygems (the gem 'rubygems') and rubygems' gem list. When you `rvm install 1.9.2` it's like you've made a completely new install of everything used with ruby.

If you'd like to get all your system ruby gems that you were previously using into your preferred rvm ruby, try this:

```
  rvm use system
  rvm gemset export system.gems
  rvm use 1.9.2
  rvm gemset import system.gems
  #You'll now have all your system gems reinstalled to your new ruby version
```

---

**Original Answer/ Edits from @Telemachus**

Try moving the lines that source rvm to the end of your `~/.bash_profile` or `~/.bashrc` (whichever you have it in):

```
'[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && . "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM function'
```

.

```
bash: /usr/bin/rails: /usr/bin/ruby1.8: bad interpreter: No such file ...
|                 |                 ^--------------------------------\
^ Bash, not rvm;  ^/usr/bin/rails, not ~/.rvm/gems/*/bin/rails;      |
                       Some ruby leftover from a previous install in the os
```

You have rails installed in `/usr/bin`, which is probably before the rvm ruby bin path in your bash `echo $PATH` variable, so it's finding the system rails install (/usr/bin/rails, a ruby script) which starts like this:

`#! /usr/bin/ruby18`

You've gotta make the conflict stop happening, the best of all possible ways is making sure that RVM's bin dir is at the beginning of your PATH. This happens in the `#Load rvm environment` script that you added to your `~/.bash_profile` when installing rvm. If you installed rvm as a system library rather than just for your user, this will be different.

If you get to that case, ask @Telemachus.

You'll then need to ensure you've gotten the rails gem installed in your new rvm ruby as above.

*Acceptance Test:*

You'll find that when you've done `rvm use 1.9.2`, then `which ruby` will return something like `~/.rvm/rubies/1.9.2/bin/ruby`, and `which rails` should return something like `~/.rvm/gems/*/bin/rails`.

Comment: done the mv, and this happens The program 'rails' is currently not installed.  You can install it by typing:
sudo apt-get install rails

Comment: after renaming, I installed it using gem install rails again, and it worked, thanks!

Comment: Please see the updated answer showing how to copy your system gems into rvm.

Comment: As for the `$PATH`, `rvm` recommends that you source it very late (ideally last) in your shell's start-up files in order to make sure that `rvm` installed items come *first*. That way, there's never a need to `mv` things out of the way as you suggest. (You really should remove that suggestion.)

Comment: +1 In general, you shouldn't have to touch system-installed items *at all* to work with `rvm`. So rather than renaming `rails`, I think the real answer is (1) install `rails` under the `rvm`-installed 1.9.2 and (2) make sure your `$PATH` is set correctly (that is, with `rvm` items *before* OS items).

Comment: @Telemachus excellent suggestion. I had assumed something strange had been occuring since the rails executable was under `/usr/bin` rather than `/usr/local/bin`, but I'm on OS X rather than one of the linuxes. I'll revamp the original suggestion to suggest moving the rvm includes in one's `~/.profile` / `~/.bashrc` / `~/.bash_profile`.

Comment: @Tim I apologize - I may have confused you. The `rvm` stuff needs to come earlier in your `$PATH`, but that means it must go last (or very late) in your profile. So above, you don't want "to the top of your `~/.bash_profile`" but "to the bottom of...". I'll probably adjust that.

Comment: Thanks! This answer fixed my issues after 5 hours of reinstalling various iterations of ruby/rvm/gems etc.

Comment: Your answer helped me twice in 2 months! :)

Answer (score 4):

I just solved the same problem on **Windows** Vista.

My console was giving me this message:

```
$ rails -v
sh: /c/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/bin/rails: C:/Projects/railsinstaller/Stage/Ruby1.9.2  /bin/ruby.exe: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

I just edited the first line of this file:

```
C:\RailsInstaller\Ruby1.9.2\bin\rails
```

And made it point to the correct location for ruby.exe, on my system, like this:

```
#!C:\RailsInstaller\Ruby1.9.2\bin\ruby.exe
```

Et voilà, problem solved!

Answer (score 0):

You need to run `rvm use --default 1.9.2`, not just `rvm use --default`.

Comment: that's what I did..but nothing