# Ruby rspec gem not found. Should I use a gemfile to solve this?

Tags: ruby, rspec, gemfile

I'm learning Ruby and Rails. I seem to have 3 versions of the rspec gem installed.

```
rspec (2.8.0, 2.7.0, 2.6.0)
rspec-core (2.8.0, 2.7.1, 2.7.0, 2.6.4)
rspec-expectations (2.8.0, 2.7.0, 2.6.0)
rspec-mocks (2.8.0, 2.7.0, 2.6.0)
```

I enter:

```sh
$ rspec spec
```

which is supposed to run all the specs in the directory spec. I get the following error:

```
/Users/Cathy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/bin/rspec:
  /Users/Cathy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/ruby:
  bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

My guess to the error is that rspec can't tell which version of the gem to use. I think I need to set up a gemfile. Are there any good directions or a better answer than mine?

I am running ruby 1.9.3p0 (2011-10-30 revision 33570) [x86_64-darwin11.2.0] on the latest MacBook Pro.

Answer (score 1):

A Gemfile is always a good idea when working with rails, or any ruby project for that matter.

Rubygems will automatically try to use the latest installed version of any gem, so that's probably not the issue here.

From the error message it looks like there's something wrong with your ruby interpreter. Notice how it says `1.9.3` on one line, and `1.9.2` on the next? That sounds a bit fishy to me, however I'm not entirely sure what to do about it.

[This SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6380373/rvm-finding-system-gems-executables) might shed some light on that matter, though.

Comment: Thanks.  I looked at that particular SO question and it didn't help.  I should have stayed with Ruby 1.9.2.  Just upgraded last Tuesday.  Still looking.

Comment: I have the same issue. Had a working setup of rails 3.2.1 on Ruby 1.9.2 (rvm). Installed Ruby 1.9.3 via rvm and migrated the gems from 1.9.2. Now, when I try to run rails, rake, whatever, I get `-bash: /Users/martijn/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/bin/rails: /Users/martijn/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/ruby: bad interpreter: No such file or directory`. Reinstalling rails didn't help, so I'm still searching for a fix too.