# RVM, Rails not Installed?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rvm

This is similar to [RVM finding system gems' executables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6380373/rvm-finding-system-gems-executables).

Everytime I try to do rails s, I get back Rails is not currently installed bla bla. If I then specify rvm --default 1.9.3, it then works. However, if I leave the app, and go back into it, same issue. Here is my PATH file..

```
# export PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:~/bin:$PATH"

  PATH=$PATH:$HOME/.rvm/bin # Add RVM to PATH for scripting

  [[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM into a shell session *as a function*
```

Comment: May be ```rvm use 1.9.3 --default``` ??

Comment: Do you actually have a .rvmrc file? Could you post the content?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use login shell, here is an example for Ubunutu: https://rvm.io/integration/gnome-terminal/